# Call a recursive function from another function in PHP

Tags: php, function, oop, object, recursion

I have created a recursive function which returns the array value. So I am calling that function from another function. but it doesn't return any values. The function is given below,

```
public function sitemapAction() {
    $sites = self::getNavigation();
    foreach(self::recursiveSitemap($sites) as $url) {
    ...
    ...
    }
}

public function recursiveSitemap($sites)
{
    $result = array();
    foreach ($sites as $site) {
        $result[]= array($site['DFA']);
        if (is_array($site['items'])) {
            return recursiveSitemap($site['items']);
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: and whats the structure returned by `self::getNavigation()`?

Comment: wow that was **helpful**. Won't bother in trying to reproduce it than.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look carefully at your recursive method, you will see that it actually does not return anything at all:

```
public function recursiveSitemap($sites)
{
    $result = array();
    foreach ($sites as $site) {
        $result[]= array($site['DFA']);
        if (is_array($site['items'])) {
            return recursiveSitemap($site['items']);
        }
    }
}
```

If your variable `$site['items']` is an array you call your method again, going deeper, without doing anything with the returned value.

And if not?

It would seem you would need to add the result you get back from your recursive function call to your `$result` array and return that, but I don't know exactly what output you expect.

Apart from that you have a small typo, you need `self::recursiveSitemap($site['items'])` if you want to call the same method recursively.

A simple example:

```
public function recursiveSitemap($sites)
{
    $result = array();
    foreach ($sites as $site) {
        if (is_array($site['items'])) {
            // do something with the result you get back
            $result[] = self::recursiveSitemap($site['items']);
        } else {
            // not an array, this is the result you need?
            $result[]= array($site['DFA']);
        }
    }
    // return your result
    return $result;
}
```

Assuming that `$result` is the thing you want to get back...

Comment: am giving a nested array as input and I want to return that $result. actaully it works in echo. but I want as a array return.

Comment: @SibiMani How can it work? Unless you have a function called `recursiveSitemap()` defined as well... I will add an example.